# connect html slider to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables, slider

I'm currently working on making my website look a bit better and I am planning to replace a current textbox input with a slider/textbox input combination, except I have no idea how to make it work within the current coding.

The current code looks as followed:

```
<tr><td>Risk:</td><td><?php  textbox('CT class=textbox',$risk,10 ); ?></td></tr>
```

$risk is set to 0 earlier in the code, and when the form is submitted it is used to decide the (obviously) risk you want to use, it ranges from 0 to 100, based on that figure some calculations are made once you hit submit.

I want to use some standard, simple slider which should look something like this:

```
<input type="range"  min="0" max="100" value="0" link-to="risktext">
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="risktext">
```

javascript part:

```
    $(function() {
  $('input').filter( function(){return this.type == 'range' } ).each(function(){  
        var $slider = $(this),
          $text_box = $('#'+$(this).attr('link-to'));

    $text_box.val(this.value);

    $slider.change(function(){
            $text_box.val(this.value);
        });

        $text_box.change(function(){
            $slider.val($text_box.val());
        });
```

The problem I experience now, and I guess it's really easy (and Im really basic at these kind of codes), is how do I link all this to change the value of $risk?

I hope anyone can help me :)

Comment: The keyword here is "AJAX". Google it.

Comment: The calculation of $risk needs to be calculated live on the server side or only when the user Submit the form?

Comment: @AlexisCôté the calculation of $risk only needs to be done when the user submits the form. He has to enter (or choose) his name, choose between either practicing or testing and this part where he/she has to choose the risks to use, then submit. So it doesn't have to change live.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic approach of what you are looking for (I think).

```
<?php 
        //Assign the risk value to 0 or the value defined in the $_POST variable.
        $risk = 0;
        if(isset($_POST['range'])) //Use the name of your control
          $risk = $_POST['range'];
        ?>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="range" name="range" min="0" max="100" value="<?php echo $risk; ?>" link-to="risktext" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="riskText" id="risktext" value="<?php echo $risk;?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This has nearly done the trick. The value the slider has, is taken when submitting. Except, the slider value isn't shown in the textbox somehow, so it's just a blind guess right now.

Comment: @kevibu I updated my answer by setting the start value of the textbox to the risk value. The reason it was not the same value is because the "onChange" event was not triggered because there was no change, only different start. You might be looking into a "create" event if you prefer to stay in JavaScript.

Comment: Either I'm doing something wrong, or it still doesn't work. Whenever I slide, the textbox doesn't change it's number, it remains 0. If I use the slider, I want the textbox value to change accordingly. I hope you understand what I mean, and that you can help me. (sorry for being stupid as well :P)